# Why are cookies still being used?

Tags: web, cookies

On every website I visit I get a pop up that it use cookies and accept their cookie policy.

While in modern browsers we have localStorage, sessionStorage, indexDB and other that I might not be aware of.

So what are the specific reasons to use it while there are a number of reasons which leads to security threats due to use of cookies.

Comment: cookies are sent back and forth with every request; local/session storage are not.

Comment: But we can add tokens while fetching from storages and these operations doesn't cost much as far as I've used them

Comment: The implication of @TZHX's comment is quite deep. Cookies allow the _server_ to identify the repeat user, even on dumb pages, even when JavaScript is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Because cookies can be used in (for example) PHP, while the localStorage and so on is only usable within the client environment.

So the new technologies are fine within any client-based application, but are not very useable in PHP or any server sided application.

Comment: Your answer is language specific Idc what PHP needs or not. @Amdan has comment which is better then your answer so Please add a little detail and make it language non specific

Comment: PHP was only an example for a server-sided language. That's the main point here. Cookies are part of each HTTP request and therefore known to the server, while the local sotrage is just client sided and not known to the server or any server based application.